# How to strip out of a reactive vector all numbers and the characters surrounding it?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In demo code shown at the bottom of this post, I'd like to strip out the number, ".", and space prefix from the "choice" column of the rendered `choices2` dataframe.

So `choice2` currently outputs this (shown in the panel labeled "Strip numbers out of reactive results ('choices2' dataframe)" when running the code):

```
  choice subclass
1   1. A        1
2   2. A        1
3   3. A        2
4   4. B        1
5   5. B        3
```

I'd instead like `choice2` to output this, stripping out the numeric prefixes (including the "." and the leading space):

```
  choice subclass
1      A        1
2      A        1
3      A        2
4      B        1
5      B        3
```

How would I do this? I know the easy way is to simply recreate the `data` DF in `choice2`, but I'm specifically trying to learn how to strip characters out from a vector or dataframe (DF) generated in a reactive context. I don't have a clear understanding of how to work with vectors/DF in a reactive setting.

Also, the code may appear cumbersome for what it does. I'd like to preserve its overall structure (use of `reactveValues()` in combination with `observeEvent()`, instead of simply using `reactive()`, for example) as it's a redaction of longer code and it's also a learning exercise.

Demo code:

```
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(choice = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), subclass = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5(strong("Base data frame ('data' dataframe):")),
  verbatimTextOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "showData",
    label = h5(strong("Multiply base DF subclass by factor of:")),
    choiceNames = c("One", "Two"),
    choiceValues = c("One", "Two"),
    selected = "One",
    inline = TRUE
  ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results ('choices1' dataframe):")),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices1"),
  h5(strong("Strip numbers out of reactive results ('choices2' dataframe):")),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$data <- renderPrint(data)
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(choices1 = c())
  
  observeEvent(input$showData, {
    rv$choices1 <- data
    rv$choices1$choice <- paste0(row.names(rv$choices1), ". ", rv$choices1$choice)
    if (input$showData == "Two") {
      rv$choices1[, 2] <- 2 * rv$choices1[, 2]
    }
  })
  
  output[["choices1"]] <- renderPrint({
    rv$choices1
  })
  
  # would like choices2 to strip number, ".", and the space out of choices1
  output[["choices2"]] <- renderPrint({
    rv$choices1
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "reactive data frame".  A reactive is a function (that may well return a data frame).  So you can't "edit" a reactive data frame.  What you can do, however, is create another reactive that takes the data frame retuned by another reactive, edit it, and then return the edited data frame as its return value.

Comment: How is the problem of string manipulation related to Shiny manipulation ?

Comment: Julien - I take it from your and Limey's comments, they are not related.

Comment: @Julien: I don't believe it is.  I think OP is using string manipulation as a trivial use case of a wider problem: how to "edit" (or manipulate) the value returned by a reactive.  As I explain in my comment, that's a question based on a misconception.  But there is an option (creation of a second reactive whose return value depends on that of another reactive) that is essentially equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment above

```
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(choice = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), subclass = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5(strong("Base data frame ('data' dataframe):")),
  verbatimTextOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "showData",
    label = h5(strong("Multiply base DF subclass by factor of:")),
    choiceNames = c("One", "Two"),
    choiceValues = c("One", "Two"),
    selected = "One",
    inline = TRUE
  ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results ('choices1' dataframe):")),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices1"),
  h5(strong("Strip numbers out of reactive results ('choices2' dataframe):")),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$data <- renderPrint(data)
  
  # Edited
  rv <- reactiveValues(choices1 = c(), choices2=NA)
  
  observeEvent(input$showData, {
    rv$choices1 <- data
    rv$choices1$choice <- paste0(row.names(rv$choices1), ". ", rv$choices1$choice)
    if (input$showData == "Two") {
      rv$choices1[, 2] <- 2 * rv$choices1[, 2]
    }
  })
  
  # New observeEvent
  observeEvent(rv$choices1, {
    rv$choices2 <- rv$choices1 %>% mutate(choice=stringr::str_sub(choice, -1))
  })
  
  output[["choices1"]] <- renderPrint({
    rv$choices1
  })
  
  # would like choices2 to strip number, ".", and the space out of choices1
  output[["choices2"]] <- renderPrint({
    # Edit here
    rv$choices2
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: OK I learned some new tricks here. I also see the use of dplyr. Thanks Limey